# Grails 2.4.3 Integration Test Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mock/web/MockAsyncContext

Tags: hibernate, grails, integration-testing, spock

I am working on a Grails app (v 2.4.3) with a legacy Oracle 10g DB and running into the below error when trying to run an integration test on a service. I've searched on both Google and here, and cannot find someone else getting this error during an integration test on a service. My unit tests on domain class run without issue, I only have this error with integration tests.

The app is structured to have all hibernate criteria calls in the service layer and cannot put them on the domain class.

```
Running 1 integration test...
| Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
| Failure:  test getAllDeliveryTypes(catalog.CatalogServiceSpec)
|  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mock/web/MockAsyncContext
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
        at grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec.initRequestEnv(IntegrationSpec.groovy:96)
        at grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec.setup(IntegrationSpec.groovy:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.mock.web.MockAsyncContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        ... 6 more
| Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 0s
```

Integration Test Class

```
package catalog

import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec
import spock.lang.*

/**
 *
 */
class CatalogServiceSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    static DeliveryType deliveryType
    static CatalogService catalogService = new CatalogService()

    def setup() {
        deliveryType = new DeliveryType()
        deliveryType.id = 1
        deliveryType.createdById = 101
        deliveryType.createdOn = new Date()
        deliveryType.modifiedById = 101
        deliveryType.modifiedOn = new Date()
        deliveryType.code = '01'
        deliveryType.name = 'In-Person Classroom'
    }

    @Unroll("test getAllDeliveryTypes")
    def "test getAllDeliveryTypes"() {


        when:
        def results = catalogService.getAllDeliveryTypes()

        then:
        results.size() == 1

    }
}
```

Service class

```
package catalog

import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class CatalogService {

    List<DeliveryType> getAllDeliveryTypes() {        

        List<DeliveryType> deliveryTypes = DeliveryType.list(sort: "id", order: "asc")        

        return deliveryTypes
    }  
}
```

Domain

```
package catalog

class DeliveryType {

    static constraints = {
        id range: 1..2500000000
        createdById range: 1..2500000000
        modifiedById range: 1..2500000000
        code maxSize: 6, unique: true
        name maxSize: 30
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        table name: 'delivery_type', schema: 'catalog'
        id generator:'assigned'
    }

    Long id
    Long createdById
    Date createdOn
    Long modifiedById
    Date modifiedOn
    String code
    String name
}
```

Config file

```
    dependencies {            
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
        runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.0.RELEASE'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"                
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Brett

Answer (score 0):

Drop the @Unroll because you don't have a where: in your spec.

In the setup phase, you aren't committing the deliveryType created. The service pulls from DeliveryType.list(), so if it isn't committed, it won't get pulled into the response.

And finally, is your dataSource setup correctly for the test environment?